# How Much Is PhoneGap Used

Tags: cordova

Is there any data out there to say how much PhoneGap is used when developing iOS and Android Apps?

Do the apps number the hundreds, or thousands, etc, or is a cross platform solution too much of a compromise for people to take it seriously?

Any other data for other cross platform solutions as to how much they are used or how popular they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PhoneGap Build** had 23,000+ applications and 10,000+ users run through it as of July 2011. They were growing at 2,000 users a month for a few months consecutively leading up to July 2011... assuming they've had similar growth over the past 7 months, then they're probably at around 20-24,000 users and 50,000+ applications (on PhoneGap Build). No idea how many of these "applications" are functional or in use, but at least it's a number, I guess.
Source: http://www.slideshare.net/AndreCharland/phone-gap-stats-growth

Outside of PhoneGap Build, there isn't an effective way to track it's usage within applications -- they kinda just wait 'til people tell them that they are using PhoneGap and link to their application. I do know that a very large majority of PhoneGap developers use it in order to develop for iPhones.

Also, you've probably run across the featured apps on the PhoneGap site, but in case you (or whoever is reading this) haven't, they're [right here](http://phonegap.com/apps/).

**August 9, 2013**: "PhoneGap has been downloaded over 1 million times and is being used by over 400,000 developers. Thousands of apps built using PhoneGap are available in mobile app stores and directories. Check out some of them here." [source: http://phonegap.com/about/](http://phonegap.com/about/)

Answer (score 5):

From Dave Johnson's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/phonegap/phonegap-at-facebook-mobile-hack) posted today: ~15,000 PhoneGap apps in app stores. Several other good metrics in the slides as well.